# jQuery script not modifying src of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, src, modal-window

I have a jQuery script that is trying to modify the `src` of an element within a modal window once an `img` on the page is clicked. It grabs the `src` of the `img` that is clicked and attempts to copy that `src` to an element in a modal pop-up window.

I've put in a test `alert(source);` within the script just to see if it's working. As expected, this alerts to the user the correct `src`. Unfortunately, the `src` is not given to the element afterward, according to the "Elements" view in the Chrome browser.

I'm trying to give the `src` to an element within the `<modal>` tags.

```
<div id="screenings">
    <?php

           ...
        //database connection
           ...

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<div class='img_div'>";
        echo "<img id='unique' class='modal_img img_screenings' ng-click=\"vm.openModal('custom-modal-1')\" src='images/".$row['image']."' >";
        ...
            echo "</div>";
        }
    ?>

</div>

<modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
                <img id="popup_img" src="#">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>

<script>
    $(".img_div").on("click", function() {
        var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        alert(source);
        $('#popup_img').prop('src', this.src);
    });
</script>
```

It's worth also noting that there is other code elsewhere that is modifying the `<modal>` element. Contained within an Angular directive file, there is this, which takes the modal and puts it at the end of the `</body>` tag:

```
   function Directive(ModalService) {

        ...

                // move element to bottom of page (just before </body>) so it can be displayed above everything else
                element.appendTo('body');

        ...

            });
```

Could that have an effect on the element within the modal not receiving the `src`?

Comment: Have you tried `$('#popup_img').attr('src', this.src);` instead?

Comment: Result appears to be the same - the `src` in `<img id="popup_img" src="#">` appears unchanged after click.

Comment: $('#popup_img').attr('src', source);

Comment: @NanheKumar ah that did it. Thank you!

Comment: @coffeebot welcome that was silly mistake :)

Comment: Be aware of `prop` in conjunction with `src` attribute. If `src` is empty it will return your page URL.

Comment: @makshh good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".img_div").on("click", function() {
    var source = $(this).find('img').attr('src');     
    $('#popup_img').attr('src', source);
});
```